# Kafka MongoDB Sink Connector Error! Not starting

Tags: bash, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to connect Kafka with MongoDB on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 ,  previously it was working fine but now I am facing an error while running.

Here is how I am trying to connect Kafka with MongoDb.

I have made a separate **connect-standalone_bare.properties** file which contains the following entities:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# These are defaults. This file just demonstrates how to override some settings.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
rest.port:8084

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets-1
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

# Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
# (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include 
# any combination of: 
# a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
# b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
# c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
# Note: symlinks will be followed to discover dependencies or plugins.
# Examples: 
# plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
plugin.path=/home/ms-batch18/Documents/kafka_2.13-2.8.0/libs/mongo-kafka-connect-1.2.0-all.jar
```

And this my MongoDb sink connector:

```
name=mongo-sink
topics=test
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
key.ignore=true
connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017
database=test_kafka
collection=transaction
max.num.retries=3
retries.defer.timeout=5000
type.name=kafka-connect
schemas.enable=false
```

While running this command:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone_bare.properties config/MongoSinkConnector.properties
```

I am facing this error:

```
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerInfo:71)
[2021-08-24 12:09:14,826] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:126)
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: config/connect-standalone_bare.properties
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:219)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:371)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:422)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:420)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:156)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:629)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.loadProps(Utils.java:616)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:75)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the property file you provided doesn't exist in the relative path of your shell.

Give the absolute path to verify it does exist.

It's also recommended to use `connect-distributed` instead